# change width of a UItableview custom cell

Tags: iphone, uitableview

Am using custom cell in my tableview with background image. when the orientation changes cell size not getting changed, I need to change the custom cell size automatically when orientation change.How can i achieve this ?

Comment: if u create u cell by xib then use autoresize. other wise set the frame again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set tableview frame programatically on delegate -

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
```

You can use

```
[tableView setFrame:[self.view.frame]];
```

Enjoy

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure to **return YES** in **shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation** method, no need to set frame **if your class is UITableViewController**.

```
// Override to allow orientations other than the default portrait orientation.
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return YES;
}
```